# What is meant by "The order of evaluation of expressions is left to right."

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Edit to clarify: **I am not asking about how sequencing works**. This question is not a duplicate of the question that it was marked as duplicate of. I already understand that `x++ * ++x` is UB. I am asking about the meaning of the phrase "The order of evaluation of expressions is left to right".

This line is taken from Bjarne Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++", 2nd edition.

I would have expected this to mean that snippets like `int x=2;int y=x++ * ++x` are well-defined. Evaluating left-to-right means, in my understanding, that `x++` is evaluated first (value 2), `++x` is evaluated second (value 4), and the final value of `y` is `8`.

But clang warns about `multiple unsequenced modifications to 'x'`, so I think my understanding of what Stroustrup's quote means must be wrong.

Can anyone explain what he actually means?

Comment: You aren't calling a function in your sample code.

Comment: @NathanOliver , I have edited to explain why I do not feel this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Reopened.  All you want to know can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 0):

"The order of expressions is left to right" means that `int z = a / b * c;` will *first* divide a by b, and *then* multiply the result with c. This will have a different result than `int z = a * c / b;`, because integer division will lose any fractions.

In 'real world ' math, the two expressions would be equivalent; in integer calculations they are not.

Comment: Counterexample: in `x+y/z`, `y/z` is evaluated first, then the addition.

Since the quote doesn't mention order of operations, I don't think this is what is meant.